# When creating an object in Django Tastypie, it resets the fields of the ForeignKey object

Tags: django, django-models, upload, tastypie

I recently updated tastypie and things started breaking everywhere. I used to use 0.11 and I recently updated to 0.16. Whenever I create  Post object, it resets the all the fields of the Foreign Key object which in this case is **poster**. Here is my resource below:

```
class UploadResource(ModelResource):
    poster = fields.ForeignKey(PosterResource, 'poster', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['post', 'get']
        resource_name = 'upload'
        authorization = Authorization()
        authentication = BasicAuthentication()
        include_resource_uri = False
        always_return_data = True
```

The **UploadResource** receives the following json from my front-end:

```
{
"description":"My new Jacket",
"url_of_image":"http:\/\/pictures.post-app.com\/bob\/08-08-201312-10-4847373978242.jpg",
"address":"",
"location_id":"",
"lat":43.637,
"lon":-79.417,
"name_of_location":"",
"poster":{"user":{"id":"3"}}
}
```

After this object is created, it resets all the fields associated with poster. It changes all those fields to blank, why is that?

Comment: You mean it creates an empty poster with just an id?

Comment: @dan-klasson nope! it actually modifies the the fields associated with the poster model. The poster model has age, bio and several other fields. Whenever a Post object is created, the bio and age and all the other fields associated with poster suddenly become blank and empty. It seems like the data is being cleared for the poster.

Comment: I can't replicate the updating behaviour you have here. Nevertheless, I'd recommend trying a custom `hydrate_poster(self, bundle)` method in your Resource that sets `bundle.data['poster']` to the appropriate `Poster` Model. This will bypass tastypie's built-in foreign key resolution, and hopefully the odd model-resetting behaviour too.